# redmine wiki - heading with auto numbering

Tags: wiki

In Redmine wiki, is there any way to use bullet point numbering in headings something like

```
# h1. Heading 1
    ## h2. Sub Heading 1
# h1. Heading 2
```

With an output like below.

```
1. Heading 1
   1.1 Sub Heading 1
2. Heading 2
```

Comment: I doubt if such a feature exists or is hidden somewhere meticulously. I've been looking for it by myself. Even after extensive searching, I could not locate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend your redmine with that macro linked here:

http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/boards/22/topics/153-hierarcial-numbered-headers

This implements exactly what you need.